# Realtime updates from Firestore via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, server

I was wondering if it's possible to update my app anytime the document is changed? I have a restaurant user that has a store of potential rewards. On the view, the user can add and delete rewards to their rewards store. Right now I have the functionality built that will allow the user to delete their reward. However, I need to refresh the page in order for the changes to show. I was wondering if there is a way to update the data in real-time via Firestore. I've watched some videos that explain how to do this on the client-side. However, my Firestore database calls happen on the server, and I'm not sure how I can update the rewards store in real-time from that.

Here is my code on the client side that adds delete functionality on the client side. It makes a call to my Node.js server which will delete the item in the restaurant's reward store.

*NOTE* The list of rewards is being obtained from the server and is passed down to the client from the server into a particular view via HTML handlebars. My concern is whether I should make these database calls from the front-end rather than the back-end.

```
for(var i = 0; i < rewardDeleteButtons.length; i++) {
    var deleteButton = rewardDeleteButtons[i]
    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(document.cookie)
        console.log(this.value)
        fetch("/deleteReward/" + this.value, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "CSRF-Token": Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"),
            },
          });
    })
}
```

Here is the code in my server that deletes the item from the Restaurant's reward store. Once I refresh my page, the changes show, but I don't know how to get that change to show in real time. The

```
app.delete('/deleteReward/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log('\n\n\n\nInside delete\n\n\n\n')
  console.log(req.params.id)

  var rewardId = req.params.id

  const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || "";

  var idToken = ""
  var type = ""
  if (sessionCookie) {
    idToken = sessionCookie['idToken']
    type = sessionCookie['type']
  }

  console.log("Printing session cookie")
  console.log(sessionCookie)
  admin
    .auth()
    .verifySessionCookie(idToken, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((decodedClaims) => {
      console.log(decodedClaims.user_id)
      deleteReward(decodedClaims.user_id, rewardId)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
})

function deleteReward(restaurantId, rewardId) {
  getRestaurant('KOBmyfQEu4urNGgBTuiJ').then(data => {
    console.log(data.rewards)
    db.collection(restaurantCollection).doc('KOBmyfQEu4urNGgBTuiJ').update({
      'rewards': FieldValue.arrayRemove({ item_points: 20, item_id: 1, item_name: 'Free Meal' })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you could send back the updated data from the `DELETE /deleteReward/` path using `res.send()` and then re-render the page on the client side using the new data?

Comment: @theusaf will that re-rendering the page require a page refresh?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have javascript on your frontend parse the new data and only replace the elements that need to be re-rendered.

Comment: @theusaf do you know how I can obtain the data from the response. Let's say I send data using res.json(key:value). On the front end I get a promise back such as promise=fetch(url...). How do I unpack that promise and get the data? When I attach a .then() function, I don't get the json value I sent back.

Comment: Maybe this will help?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can use set a [Firestore listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) on you client app:

```js
db.collection(restaurantCollection)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified Restaurant: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed Restaurant: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

This will trigger whenever a document is added/modified/removed. Then you can check `change.type` and if it's "removed", just delete that restaurant div from the DOM.

---

The `deleteReward` is updating the document and not deleting it. So you should check for `change.type === "modified"` on client.